# Why can I not access `::class.companionObject`?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, companion-object, kotlin-reflect, kotlin-companion

I am trying to access the companion object of an unknown class with a known interface, given an instance of the class.

Code below:

```kotlin
class AccessTest() {
    companion object {
        val prop = 5
    }
    fun getComp() {
        print(this)
        print(this::class)
        print(this::class.companionObject) // Unresolved reference.
        print(this::class.companionObjectInstance) // Unresolved reference.
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> getCompanion() {
    print(T::class.companionObject) // Unresolved reference.
    print(T::class.companionObjectInstance) // Unresolved reference.
}

fun main() {
    AccessTest().getComp()
    getCompanion<AccessTest>()
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ kotlinc -d main.jar main.kt && kotlin -classpath main.jar MainKt
main.kt:8:27: error: unresolved reference: companionObject
        print(this::class.companionObject) // Unresolved reference.
                          ^
main.kt:9:27: error: unresolved reference: companionObjectInstance
        print(this::class.companionObjectInstance) // Unresolved reference.
                          ^
main.kt:14:20: error: unresolved reference: companionObject
    print(T::class.companionObject) // Unresolved reference.
                   ^
main.kt:15:20: error: unresolved reference: companionObjectInstance
    print(T::class.companionObjectInstance) // Unresolved reference.
                   ^
```

I do not think this is a duplicate of either of the below questions, as I am specifically asking what has changed or what I am misunderstanding such that the solution in the two below questions is not working for me:

[how to access companion object from object instance in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46827060/12260302)

[Kotlin invoke companion function with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59108030/12260302)

Comment: Did you add the `kotlin-reflect` dependency to your module/project?

Comment: @broot In the project, yes. The test code, I just ran with `kotlinc`/`kotlin`— Same result if I `import kotlin.reflect.*`. I believe the error message is different if missing the dependency. It will explicitly say `Kotlin reflection is not available` or, or complain about missing `kotlin-reflect.jar`?

Comment: if I don't add `kotlin-reflect` then my IntelliJ just says "unresolved reference". Maybe Android Studio behave differently, I don't know. Generally speaking, compiler and IDEs usually don't know about possible additional libs, so "unresolved reference" is a typical message if you miss a dependency. Anyway, I'm pretty sure you need `kotlin-reflect` for this to work, so I would be surprised if your `kotlinc` would succeed.

Comment: Oh, my bad. `kotlinc` actually includes `kotlin-reflect` by default.

Comment: So another question is: did you import `companionObject`? I ask because if you use `kotlinc` manually then maybe you don't use IDE at all, so it doesn't handle imports for you. You said that you imported `kotlin.reflect.*`, but `companionObject` is not there. It's in `kotlin.reflect.full.*`.

Comment: @broot Oh! Solved! Thank you! Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it, or would it perhaps be better if I deleted this question and then left a comment/proposed an edit to the answer on the other existing question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short discussion in comments, it turned out it was just a missing import.

`companionObject` is not a member of `KClass`, but extension on it, so it is possible we have access to `KClass` object, but we don't see its `companionObject` property. Also, as it's the part of `kotlin-reflect` library, it is not located in `kotlin.reflect` package, but in `kotlin.reflect.full`, so importing `kotlin.reflect.*` isn't enough to get it.