# How to access function of companion object using class object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, companion-object, kotlin-companion

In Kotlin, we can access function or property of companion object using class name as following:

```kotlin
class DemoClass {
    companion object {
        fun someFunction() {}
    }
}

// Accessing function
DemoClass.someFunction()
```

But how can I access the same function if I have an object of `DemoClass`?

```kotlin
class DemoClass {
    companion object {
        fun someFunction() {}
    }
}

val demoObj = DemoClass()

// I cannot do following - It will not compile.
demoObj.someFunction()
```

Basically, I want to access companion function using class object.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just do `DemoClass.someFunction()`?

Comment: `someFunction()` is a companion object, so not related to an instance of `DemoClass`.

Comment: Try calling  `DemoClass.someFunction()`. Companion Object is static reference. To access the function, method or varaible inside companion object no need to create class instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access companion object from object instance in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827060/how-to-access-companion-object-from-object-instance-in-kotlin)